# Compare Quaternion to axis

Tags: geometry, rotation, quaternions, rigid-bodies

I have the orientation of an object stored as a unit quaternion, and I want to see what angle the object's local x axis makes with the global y axis.  What's the easiest way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was overthinking it... rotate the vector (1, 0, 0), the local x axis into the global frame.  Dot it with the global y vector, and take the arcCos of it.  Since I didn't care about the object being upside down, I took

```
acos(abs(rotateVector(myQuat, vector(1, 0, 0)), upVector))
```